# What type of foam to fill this pipe hole?

Tags: pipe, hole, spray-foam, hole-repair

There is a strong smell that comes from underneath my kitchen sink. All the wood is brand new so I guess it's coming from the hole in the ground in the picture.

I have seen different types of spray foams that can be used to fill holes. Is there any specific brand or type I should use? That will get in that deep hole good to seal it up... where the pipe is coming out of the ground.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Great Stuff can be used, but I would not fill it with anything especially if I did not know what it was - its purpose.

You really should find out what the purpose of that pipe is. Is the pipe part of an old drain left after a **bad remodel**, a vent pipe?

If the pipe is PVC or Metal you can just cap it off - they make caps for these pipes less than $5 USA.

Comment: I would find a way to cover the hole with a thin material instead of filling in the hole, in case you need access to that area at  a later date

Comment: It's hard to tell from this angle but is there a cable of some sort running into that hole? It sort of looks like a dark colored Romex cable. I wonder if a small rodent got in there and died and that is what you are smelling.

Comment: That pipe is not open...it for the running water to the facet. In that case, would it be ok to fill that hole? It is so deep underneath the cabenit I can not get in there to cover it with tape.

Comment: @dman the picture angle makes it difficult to see - but is there a power cable coming out of that pipe - you say it is a water pipe for the faucet ??  but how does water go from that  open pipe into a closed faucet system ? Are you understanding why we have these questions - ? Can you take a picture form another angle and post that (perhaps more of a side angle - from the right hand side of the picture you posted ??)

Comment: @ken I uploaded some more photos to give context of the water valve in pipe